# Cancelling and restarting a task

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

I have read a few articles about this but I am currently none-the-wiser. I'm working on an application where there is a TabControl located on the form. When the user clicks on a tab page, I would like the background process to run off of the UI thread (as the process can take several minutes). This is fine, however if the user selects a different tab, I would like any currently active task to cancel, and for the attention to go to the new tab.

```
private void ParentTabControl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task testTask;
        CancellationTokenSource testSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken testToken = testSource.Token;

        switch (ParentTabControl.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                updateSummaryTab();
                break;
            case 1:
                testTask = Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        updateTabOne();
                    }, testToken);
                break;
            case 2:
                updateTabTwo();
                break;
        }
    }
```

If I set the testSource to cancel, then this will no longer by usable (though I am aware that I will need to use a token of some kind). I was previously using a different BackgroundWorker for each tab and simply checking the IsBusy property of it, but I thought using a single recycled Task may be the better option.

Comment: What concrete problem are you having? Seems like all you have to do is cancel any outstanding work when tabs are switched and start new work.

Comment: The problem I get is when I cancel the task using the CancellationToken, the new task fails to launch (presumably because it is using the same token, which is now set as cancelled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem I get is when I cancel the task using the CancellationToken, the new task fails to launch

Create a fresh CTS (and CT) for each round of work that you are starting. You need to store the CTS for the last round in a field. Then, starting new work is:

```
if(cts != null) cts.Cancel();
cts = new ...;
StartWork(cts.Token);
```

Be aware, that cancelling running tasks is cooperative and passing the token to `Task.Run` does nothing because it does not stop the already running task.

Comment: I had a feeling I would have to recycle the CancellationTokenSource, I just couldn't get my head around how. If passing the Token to the Task doesn't cancel it when the Task is running (but using cts.Cancel() does), would there be any point in using a Token?

Comment: You need to pass the token into "StartWork" and use it there. Poll it or pass it to IO methods.

Comment: Ah, it seems that running Tasks cannot be cancelled. Would you recommend me going back to using the BackgroundWorker in this instance?

Comment: No. BackgroundWorker is obsolete. It can't be cancelled either. Do you understand that you can cancel work in a cooperative way? Pass the token to IO methods etc. They can be cancelled.

Comment: This is the first I have heard of cancelling work in a cooperative way; seems like I have some more reading to do. Thanks for your assistance